# Why does keyframe-based animation slow down in the end?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have this simple loading indicator:

https://jsbin.com/putuloledu/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Load indicator slowing down</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .timeIndicator {
    height: 5px;
    width: 0;
    background: #12b3c4;
    animation-name: indicator-load;
    animation-duration: 7s;
}

@keyframes indicator-load {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }
    to {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
    </style>
<div class="timeIndicator"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which is supposed to show a self-growing rectangle indicator which grows evenly then stops at 200px width.

As can be seen, no easing is added anyhow.

Why then the animation slows down in the end and how to disable it making it even from start to end?

Comment: you need to make the ease linear ... as the default one is not linear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i have understood you correctly this is what you may need 
just use the `animation-timing-function:linear` 
here i have done it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Load indicator slowing down</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .timeIndicator {
    height: 5px;
    width: 0;
    background: #12b3c4;
    animation-name: indicator-load;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes indicator-load {
    from {
        width: 0;
    }
    to {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
    </style>
<div class="timeIndicator"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the `animation-timing-function` `animation` property.